# APT-GET: How to retrieve the description of all packages that have a certain string in their name?

Tags: bash

I wish to inspect all packages which have the string 'Terminal' in their names. Currently I can do so by issuing the following command:

```
apt-cache show someterminalpackage
```

However, there are a number of such packages, and I wish to look at the description of all of them in one go. Thus far, I have tried using xargs but I do not know how to extract the name of the package and then issue the above command on it.

Would you know how to do this?

Thanks!

The output from a single `apt-get show` is of the form:

```
package-name -  abbreivate package info
```

For example:

```
mg - microscopic GNU Emacs-style editor
```

**Update**:

Not strictly the requirement, but I am trying to run these commands on an iPhone. It would be awesome to hear from people who have a jailbroken iphone (6.x).

Comment: It's not apt-get show it's apt-cache show.

Comment: Do you want to run the above command on all the installed packages which has terminal on their name?

Comment: Yes, I want to run this command on all such packages (not just installed ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit rough and ready, but this should do the job:

```
apt-cache search terminal | cut -d "-" -f 1 | grep terminal | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo %; apt-cache show %; echo -e "\n"' > terminals.txt
```

Let me break that command down:

`apt-cache search terminal` : This searches for all packages which contain the string 'Terminal' in either their name or the description.

`| cut -d "-" -f 1` : Extracts the package name (assumes that their are no hyphens in the package name)

`| grep terminal` : Does a grep again to search for 'terminal' in the extracted package names.

and finally,

`| xargs -I % bash -c 'echo %; apt-cache show %; echo -e "\n"' > terminals.txt` : Runs the apt-cache show command on each of the package names.

Is this closer to what you wanted ?

FYI, tested on a JB'ed iPhone with 6.1.3 :)

Comment: Great !!! This is exactly what I wanted.  I can see that there is one package with an hyphen name which gets corrupted, but I can live with that. Thank you!!

Comment: No, `apt-cache search terminal` gives the list of all the packages that are related to terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below command,

```
apt-cache search all | awk -F' - ' '{ print $1}' | grep terminal | xargs -I {} apt-cache show {}
```

Comment: Nice, this works too !! I seem to get an error at the end though : W: `Unable to locate package {}`, would you know why that might be ?

Answer (score 1):

Use apt-cache this way:

```
apt-cache search <your string>
```

Comment: op wants the "terminal" string in the package name.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good way to go about it, however, this shows the abbreivated information for each package and I need the detail shown by `apt-cache show` for each of these packages

Answer (score 0):

Combine `apt-cache search` and `apt-cache show`:

```
apt-cache show $(apt-cache search <packagename>)
```

like

```
apt-cache show $(apt-cache search vim) | less
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was hoping for, but I do not see the detailed information for all the packages I would expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to search only the package names, then you need `apt-cache pkgnames`:

```
apt-cache pkgnames \
| grep -i terminal \
| xargs apt-cache show
```